# Using Cucumber/Gherkin for application code generation

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I am relatively new to the world of BDD, Cucumber and Gherkin, so this may be a nonsense question.

I have written a couple of feature files and associated step definitions, so I have a basic understanding of using this to test my application.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to use feature files to generate the application code, effectively using the step definitions to output code rather than test it?

Assuming it was possible, is it a bad idea, and if so, why?

Thanks,

Carl

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you? If so, would you mind upvoting and selecting my answer as the correct one? If not, would you leave a comment so that I could edit my answer to it could be of help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to say it is a bad idea. What I will say is that this tool (Cucumber) is not intended for that purpose. I will give you this analogy. You can drive a nail into a wall with a screwdriver. But, isn't it a better idea to use a hammer instead?

The scenario that you are describing is as follows, and correct me if I am wrong. You want to pass data into a function. Then you want that function to make decisions based on the data you are providing and spit out a particular type of output. In this case, you want your function to spit out code. In short, I will express that in BDD:

```
Given a transformer function f(x)
When 'x' is a valid text string
Then function f(x) generates code snippet
```

If the above is true, what you need is a ***Business Rule Management System***. One such system I know is called [Drools](https://www.drools.org/). In 2018, I created such an application. I used Drools to create the business rules that would read text, make some inferences based on the rules I created, and write code snippets. Then, I collected those snippets and put them inside a Java class (.java) template I created and doing a simple string operation, I concatenated my snippets into a Java test method. In essence, the rules engine created ".java" files on the fly, which were then compiled and executed by a test engine (JUnit if my memory serves me well).

I have to warn you, this is a lot harder than you may think. Creating the rules to convert plain text into code can be EXTREMELY difficult.